# Using WTForms with Enum

Tags: python, flask, enums, wtforms

I have the following code:

```
class Company(enum.Enum):
    EnterMedia = 'EnterMedia'
    WhalesMedia = 'WhalesMedia'

    @classmethod
    def choices(cls):
        return [(choice.name, choice.name) for choice in cls]

    @classmethod
    def coerce(cls, item):
        print "Coerce", item, type(item)
        if item == 'WhalesMedia':
            return Company.WhalesMedia
        elif item == 'EnterMedia':
            return Company.EnterMedia
        else:
            raise ValueError
```

And this is my wtform field:

```
company = SelectField("Company", choices=Company.choices(), coerce=Company.coerce)
```

This is the html generated in my form:

```
<select class="" id="company" name="company" with_label="">
    <option value="EnterMedia">EnterMedia</option>
    <option value="WhalesMedia">WhalesMedia</option>
</select>
```

Somehow, when I click submit, I keep getting "Not a Valid Choice".

### Any ideas why?

This is my terminal output:

When I look at my terminal I see the following:

```
Coerce None <type 'NoneType'>
Coerce EnterMedia <type 'unicode'>
Coerce EnterMedia <type 'str'>
Coerce WhalesMedia <type 'str'>
```

Comment: You can map string names to objects (*coerce*) simply by indexing the enum: `Company["EnterMedia"]` produces `Company.EnterMedia`. You can use `coerce=Company.__getitem__`. Calling works too, for *values*, so `coerce=Company`. See See [*Programmatic access*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes). Your names and values match, so you can use either here.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
class Company(enum.Enum):
  WhalesMedia = 'WhalesMedia'
  EnterMedia = 'EnterMedia'

  @classmethod
  def choices(cls):
    return [(choice, choice.value) for choice in cls]

  @classmethod
  def coerce(cls, item):
    """item will be both type(enum) AND type(unicode).
    """
    if item == 'Company.EnterMedia' or item == Company.EnterMedia:
      return Company.EnterMedia
    elif item == 'Company.WhalesMedia' or item == Company.WhalesMedia:
      return Company.WhalesMedia
    else:
      print "Can't coerce", item, type(item)
```

So I hacked around and this works.

It seems to me that coerce will be applied to both (x,y) for (x,y) in choices.

I can't seem to understand why I keep seeing: `Can't coerce None <type 'NoneType'>` though

Comment: See my solution, it's considerably cleaner

Answer (score 5):

WTForm will either pass in strings, `None`, or *already coerced data* to `coerce`; this is a little annoying but easily handled by testing if the data to coerce is already an instance:

```
isinstance(someobject, Company)
```

The `coerce` function must otherwise raise a `ValueError` or `TypeError` when coercing.

You want to use the *enum names* as the values in the select box; these are always going to be strings. If your enum *values* are suitable as labels, then that's great, you can use those for the option readable text, but don't confuse those with the option values, which must be unique, enum values do not need to be.

`Enum` classes let you map a string containing an enum name to the `Enum` instance by using subscription:

```
enum_instance = Company[enum_name]
```

See [*Programmatic access to enumeration members and their attributes*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes) in the `enum` module documentation.

Next, we could leave conversion of the enum objects to unique strings (for the `value="..."` attribute of `<option>` tags) and to label strings (to show to the users) to standard hook methods on the enum class, such as `__str__` and `__html__`.

Together, for your specific setup, use:

```
from markupsafe import escape

class Company(enum.Enum):
    EnterMedia = 'Enter Media'
    WhalesMedia = 'Whales Media'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name  # value string

    def __html__(self):
        return self.value  # label string

def coerce_for_enum(enum):
    def coerce(name):
        if isinstance(name, enum):
            return name
        try:
            return enum[name]
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError(name)
    return coerce

company = SelectField(
    "Company",
    # (unique value, human-readable label)
    # the escape() call can be dropped when using wtforms 3.0 or newer
    choices=[(v, escape(v)) for v in Company],
    coerce=coerce_for_enum(Company)
)
```

The above keeps the Enum class implementation separate from the presentation; the `cource_for_enum()` function takes care of mapping `KeyError`s to `ValueError`s. The `(v, escape(v))` pairs provide the value and label for each option; `str(v)` is used for the `<option value="...">` attribute value, and that same string is then used via `Company[__html__result]` to coerce back to enum instances. WTForms 3.0 will start using `MarkupSafe` for labels, but until then, we can directly provide the same functionality with `escape(v)`, which in turn uses `__html__` to provide a suitable rendering.

If having to remember about what to put in the list comprehension, and to use `coerce_for_enum()` is becoming tedious, you can generate the `choices` and `coerce` options with a helper function; you could even have it verify that there are suitable `__str__` and `__html__` methods available:

```
def enum_field_options(enum):
    """Produce WTForm Field instance configuration options for an Enum

    Returns a dictionary with 'choices' and 'coerce' keys, use this as
    **enum_fields_options(EnumClass) when constructing a field:

    enum_selection = SelectField("Enum Selection", **enum_field_options(EnumClass))

    Labels are produced from str(enum_instance.value) or 
    str(eum_instance), value strings with str(enum_instance).

    """
    assert not {'__str__', '__html__'}.isdisjoint(vars(enum)), (
        "The {!r} enum class does not implement __str__ and __html__ methods")

    def coerce(name):
        if isinstance(name, enum):
            # already coerced to instance of this enum
            return name
        try:
            return enum[name]
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError(name)

    return {'choices': [(v, escape(v)) for v in enum], 'coerce': coerce}
```

and for your example, then use

```
company = SelectField("Company", **enum_field_options(Company))
```

Note that once WTForm 3.0 is released, you can use a `__html__` method on enum objects without having to use `markdownsafe.escape()`, because the project is [switching to using MarkupSafe for the label values](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/pull/400).

Answer (score 4):

I've just been down the same rabbit hole. Not sure why, but `coerce` gets called with `None` when the form is initialised. After wasting a lot of time, I decided it's not worth coercing, and instead I just used:

```
field = SelectField("Label", choices=[(choice.name, choice.value) for choice in MyEnum])
```

and to get the value:

```
selected_value = MyEnum[field.data]
```

Comment: Works and validates too.

Answer (score 4):

This is a lot cleaner than the accepted solution, as you don't need to put the options more than once.

By default Python will convert objects to strings using their path, which is why you end up with Company.EnterMedia and so on. In the below solution, I use `__str__` to tell python that the name should be used instead, and then use the [] notation to look up the enum object by the name.

```
class Company(enum.Enum):
    EnterMedia = 'EnterMedia'
    WhalesMedia = 'WhalesMedia'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @classmethod
    def choices(cls):
        return [(choice, choice.value) for choice in cls]

    @classmethod
    def coerce(cls, item):
        return item if isinstance(item, Company) else Company[item]
```

Comment: Don't use `type(...) == ...`, ever. You want `isinstance(item, Company)`, or if subclasses are not permissable, use `type(item) is Company` (note the identity test, not equality). Concrete `Enum` classes are not sub-classable, so `isinstance()` is more than fine.

Comment: And `coerce()` will never be called with an enum instance, because WTF deals with strings, exclusively!

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to convert the argument passed to `coerce` method into an instance of the enum.

```
import enum

class Company(enum.Enum):
    EnterMedia = 'EnterMedia'
    WhalesMedia = 'WhalesMedia'

    @classmethod
    def choices(cls):
        return [(choice.name, choice.value) for choice in cls]

    @classmethod
    def coerce(cls, item):
        item = cls(item) \
               if not isinstance(item, cls) \
               else item  # a ValueError thrown if item is not defined in cls.
        return item.value
        # if item.value == 'WhalesMedia':
        #     return Company.WhalesMedia.value
        # elif item.value == 'EnterMedia':
        #     return Company.EnterMedia.value
        # else:
        #     raise ValueError
```

Comment: I gave this a try and it doesn't work, getting a "Not a valid choice". 

This is what's being rendered:
`<select id="company" name="company"><option selected value="EnterMedia">EnterMedia</option><option value="WhalesMedia">WhalesMedia</option></select>`.

And this is what form.company.data = `Company.WhalesMedia (type:<enum 'Company'>)`

Comment: I believe the error arise from Enum.coerce mapping form.data to an enum but WTForm's SelectField is looking for a string since that's what's given in choices

Comment: @Sparrowcide I updated the answer to return the value in the enum field.

Comment: Mapping string names to enum objects is done by using `[...]`: `Company['EnterMedia']`. See [*Programmatic access*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes). Calling can work too, for *values*.

Answer (score 1):

The function pointed to by the `coerce` parameter needs to convert the string delivered by the browser (the value of the `<select>`ed `<option>`) into the type of the values you specified in your `choices`:

> Select fields keep a `choices` property which is a sequence of (`value`, `label`) pairs. The value portion can be any type in theory, but as form data is sent by the browser as strings, you will need to provide a function which can coerce the string representation back to a comparable object.

https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.2.1/fields.html#wtforms.fields.SelectField

That way the [coerced provided value](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/src/wtforms/fields/core.py#L538) can be [compared with the configured ones](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/src/wtforms/fields/core.py#L545).

Since you are already using the name *strings* of your enum items as values (`choices=[(choice.name, choice.name) for choice in Company]`), there is no coercing for you to do.

If you decided to use *integer* `Enum::value`s as the values for the `<option>`s, you'd have to coerce the returned strings back into `int`s for comparison.

```
choices=[(choice.value, choice.name) for choice in Company],
coerce=int
```

If you wanted to get enum items out of your form, you'd have to configure those in your `choices` (`[(choice, choice.name) for choice in Company]`) and coerce their string serialization (e.g. `Company.EnterMedia`) back into `Enum` instances, dealing with the issues mentioned in the other answers such as `None` and coerced enum instances being passed into your function:

Given you return the `Company::name` in `Company::__str__` and using `EnterMedia` as a default:

```
coerce=lambda value: value if isinstance(value, Company) else Company[value or Company.EnterMedia.name]
```

Hth, dtk

Answer (score 0):

Here a different method that just creates a new WTF EnumField and does some class manipulation on the enum-type to make it seamlessly usable with these function:

```
import enum

@enum.unique
class MyEnum(enum.Enum):
    foo = 0
    bar = 10
```

then create the EnumField definition somewhere, which just extends SelectField to use Enum-types:

```
import enum
from markupsafe import escape
from wtforms import SelectField

from typing import Union, Callable


class EnumField(SelectField):
    def coerce(enum_type: enum.Enum) -> Callable[[Union[enum.Enum, str]], enum.Enum]:
        def coerce(name: Union[enum.Enum, str]) -> enum.Enum:
            if isinstance(name, enum_type):
                return name
            try:
                return enum_type[name]
            except KeyError:
                raise ValueError(name)
        return coerce

    def __init__(self, enum_type: enum.Enum, *args, **kwargs):
        def attach_functions(enum_type: enum.Enum) -> enum.Enum:
            enum_type.__str__ = lambda self: self.name
            enum_type.__html__ = lambda self: self.name
            return enum_type

        _enum_type = attach_functions(enum_type)
        super().__init__(_enum_type.__name__,
            choices=[(v, escape(v)) for v in _enum_type],
            coerce=EnumField.coerce(_enum_type), *args, **kwargs)
```

now in your code, you can use stuff naively:

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    field__myenum = EnumField(MyEnum)
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

@app.route("/action", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def action():
    form = MyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print('Enum value is: ', form.field__myenum)  #<MyEnum.foo: 0>
        return redirect(url_for('.action'))
    elif request.method == 'GET':  # display the information on record
        form.field__myenum.data = MyEnum.foo
        form.field__myenum.default = MyEnum.foo
    return render_template('action.html', form=form)
```